Is it possible to extract images from a .gpkg exported from Avenza?
I use the mobile app Avenza Maps which lets you place points/lines/polygons and export those data to kml as well as ESRI Shapefile (.shp) and OGC GeoPackage (.gpkg) if you have a paid subscription. I was playing around with exporting some of my data into a .gpkg format. It exported the geospatial data just fine, and I was able to open and view it in QGIS. But I have several photos attached to those data which I cannot view. The exported .gpkg contains a layer called "avenza media" which has entries with Blobs that I believe are supposed to represent the images. However, I can't find a way to access the images themselves.
I found this question, which seems to be about creating the .gpkg within QGIS and storing a photo within it. However, I'm trying to go the other way - open an image that should be stored in the .gpkg already. I tried looking at Avenza's website, but it doesn't give much information about how it exports GeoPackages and how it handles images.
Does anyone know if there's a way to retrieve those photos after export?
EDIT: Spacedman's comment below provided a solution - I added it as an answer.

The images will be in your photo library and not in any file exported by Avenza.  https://support.avenzamaps.com/hc/en-us/articles/5051510751892-Plot-Photos-Tool

Any chance you can share a GeoPackage file with us? Do the blobs (and the geopackage file itself) look big enough to store the actual photo data? Maybe the blobs only have photo metadata?

@GBG Thanks for looking into this! I'm not seeing the part in the linked article that mentions image export. If it matters, I'm not using the Plot Photos tool, I'm using the option to place a placemark and then adding an image to that. I know that the files are stored locally, but since the .kml export option lets you extract the images from the output file I thought it might be the same for GeoPackages.

@Spacedman the specific GeoPackage has some sensitive data so I'm not sure I can share that. However, when I exported a test .gpkg from an Avenza layer with photos it was larger (308 KB) than without (228 KB). The same photos exported in a .kml totaled 75 KB (I used the "small" option when exporting so they're compressed) so the file size seems about right. However, it could also be photo metadata making the file bigger.

Try writing the binary BLOBs to files, they might be straight JPEGs stored as binary. Not really a GIS Q now since GeoPackages are SQLite3 files so you might want to try vanilla stack overflow or maybe this helps: https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-blob-insert-and-retrieve-digital-data/

@Spacedman this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! For anyone else who might find this question, you can connect to a .gpkg file as an SQLite3 database using the built in sqlite3 python library. The script in the pynative tutorial link above worked perfectly with just a few edits to fit my specific file (i.e., in the Avenza-exported .gpkg, the BLOB column is index 1, the photo name is index 7, and you'll most likely want to be selecting based on the 'fid' column most likely)

Nice! You should probably put your answer in as a "answer" in the "Your Answer" box, instead of an edit to your Q, then stack overflow knows this question has been answered!

Spacedman's comment below fixed this issue. You can can connect to a .gpkg file as an SQLite3 database using the built in sqlite3 Python library. The script in this tutorial they found works almost perfectly, you would just need to modify it for your specific .gpkg. I imagine ones that come out of Avenza all have a similar structure.
import sqlite3
data = sqlite3.connect('filename.gpkg')
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
#The output table with my photos in it was called avenza_media
#I selected by the fid column so used this query to get the first row's record
blob_query = """SELECT * from avenza_media where fid = ?"""
cursor.execute(blob_query, (1,))
record = cursor.fetchall()

Then, if you know the index of the column with the blob, you can get that columns from that row and write the blob to a new file using file.write(). In my Avenza export, it was the second column (index 1), called "data".
for row in record:
    photo = row[1]
    with open('output_image.jpg', 'wb') as filepath:
        file.write(photo)


You might want to pose your questions directly to Avenza. They have excellent tech support and are very responsive. support@avenza.com

@Mr. Mojo Risin' I think it's more of a GIS/scripting issue than a coding issue - Avenza's GeoPackage exported correctly, I just didn't know how to extract the image data from the BLOB column
